# Xcode Convert .a library file to arm64 arch supportive .a file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, 64-bit, xcode6.1

I have old libraries in my project which do not support 64 bit architecture.I dont have source of those libraries.I have just .a files of those libraries.Is there any way that I can convert these libraries to 64 bit supportive libraries?

Comment: AFAIK it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile the project on 64 bit architecture. Since you don't have the source code, unfortunately it's **NOT possible** to convert the library to support 64 bit architecture.

Probably the only thing you can do is searching the web for other versions of this library. If you find anything, you can use this terminal command to check what architectures it is supporting:

```
 lipo -info LIB_NAME.a
```

Comment: I have already searched for other versions.64 bit not available right now.I am asking that is there any way to convert existing library into 64 bit without any code?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can't do that. I just added an easy way to check what architectures library is supporting.